# Issue while checking if Table exisits in Sqlite database in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone application, i am checking if a table exists in database using following code

```
 var connection = new SQLiteConnection(_dbpathlocal);
 var isExist = connection.Query<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='version';");
```

The isExist always has the value 0 even if table exists.

I also tried the following query

```
var isExist = connection.Query<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM version");
```

This also returns 0 even though the table has data.

Am i doing something wrong ??

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with query , take a look at the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671)

Comment: Show the exact CREATE TABLE statement.